# Nativescript - how to display image from documents directory?

Tags: imageview, nativescript

I'm building an app that's mostly intended for offline usage.
A user can download an image from the web, and I can see that uploaded image within the documents folder (fs.knownFolders.documents()) within my Nativescript app without problem.

I've spent the last few hours trying to display that downloaded image within my view, without success.

From what I understand (could be wrong) this is different than just specifying an image src of "~/myImage.jpg".

Although this isn't my exact application, this follows the same principles and give us some code to verify against.

**main-page.js:**

```
var observable = require("data/observable");
var imageSource = require("image-source");
var fs = require("file-system");

exports.pageLoaded = function() {

    var viewModel = new observable.Observable();
    http.getFile("https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png").then(function (r) {
        //the getFile downloads to the root documents path, shown below

        var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
        var path = fs.path.join(folder.path, "googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
        var image = imageSource.fromFile(path);
        //have also tried grabbing the image by id, and setting its src.

        viewModel.set("image", image);

    }, function (e) {
        //// Argument (e) is Error!
    });
    viewModel.set("image", null);

    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

}
```

and **main-page.xml:**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image width="80" src="{{image}}" height="80" stretch="none" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

For reference, I'm using tns javascript (not angular), and tns version 2.0.1.  At this point in time, I'm only concerned about iOS.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Use `http.getImage`

2) Grab the `Image` view via it's ID

3) Set the `imageSource` to the response of `getImage`

4)Save file

```
http.getImage("https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png").then(function (r) {
        var imgview = page.getViewById("id_of_image_view");
        imgview.imageSource = r;
        var saved = imgView.imageSource.saveToFile(path,'jpg');

    }};
```

Comment: I'm feeling pretty stupid now - basically the only thing I needed here was the `imageSource` attribute.  It wasn't too clear from the cookbooks docs.

Comment: Hello. I am attempting something similar however I am using typescript. The  compiler complains that "imageSource is not a property of view". Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: @xerotolerant your field retrieved by `page.getViewById` must be casted to `Image`: `const img: Image = <Image>page.getViewById("id");` Without the cast the implicit type is View which does not own the property like your error message already documented.